# Left Drawer fixing items multiselection

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I need to fix multiselection fo items. when I select one of the items, it changes it`s color. But when I open left drawer once more it remains selected. I need to discard any selected items in 2 cases: 1) when I press another item, the selected item must become unselected. 2) when left drawer closes, the selection must discard.[image]

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/GsiTheme", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainPageActivity : AppCompatActivity, IActivityWithToolbar
{

    #region Views
    [InjectView(Resource.Id.mainpageToolbar)]
    SupportToolbar _toolbar;

    [InjectView(Resource.Id.navigation_view)]
    NavigationView _navigationView;

    [InjectView(Resource.Id.drawer)]
    DrawerLayout _drawer;

    #endregion

    ActionBarDrawerToggle _drawerToggle;

    public SupportToolbar Toolbar
    {
        get
        {
            return _toolbar;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<int, Type> _fragmentTypesById = new Dictionary<int, Type>() {
        {Resource.Id.categoriesMenuItem,typeof(CategoriesListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.opportunitiesMenuItem,typeof(OpportunitiesListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.prospectsMenuItem,typeof(ProspectsListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.suppliersMenuItem,typeof(SuppliersListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.accountsMenuItem,typeof(AccountsListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.fabricantsMenuItem,typeof(ManufacturersListfragment)},
        {Resource.Id.contactsMenuItem,typeof(ContactsListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.productsMenuItem,typeof(ProductsListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.warehouseMenuItem,typeof(WarehouseListFragment)},
        {Resource.Id.stockMenuItem,typeof(StocksListFragment)}

    };

    int _selectedPageMenuId;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mainPagelayout);

            Cheeseknife.Inject(this);
            initUi();
            //var ft = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            //ft.Add(Resource.Id.mainPageFragmentHolder, new CategoriesListFragment());
            //ft.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();

        }

    }

    private void initFragmentByMenuId(int menuId)
    {

        if (_selectedPageMenuId == menuId)
            return;


        if (!_fragmentTypesById.ContainsKey(menuId))
            return;

        var currFragment = Activator.CreateInstance(_fragmentTypesById[menuId]) as Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.mainPageFragmentHolder, currFragment, currFragment.GetType().Name);
        ft.Commit();

        _selectedPageMenuId = menuId;

    }

    void navigationItem_selected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        _navigationView.Menu.FindItem(e.MenuItem.ItemId).SetChecked(true);

        initFragmentByMenuId(e.MenuItem.ItemId);

        _drawer.CloseDrawers();

    }

    void subscribeEvents()
    {

        _navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += navigationItem_selected;
    }

    void unSubscribeEvents()
    {
        _navigationView.NavigationItemSelected -= navigationItem_selected;
    }

    void initUi()
    {

        SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.Title = "Dashboard";
        _drawerToggle = new CustActionBarDrawToggle(this, _drawer, 0, 0);

        _drawer.AddDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
        _drawerToggle.SyncState();

        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        _drawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnStart();
            subscribeEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnStop();
            unSubscribeEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can quite easily achieve what you want to, by always saving the last selected item and making sure it's unselected before selecting the new one.

```
MenuItem lastSelected;

void navigationItem_selected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    // If another item is already selected
    if(lastSelected != null) {
        lastSelected.SetChecked(false);
    }

    // Save the handle to the new item and select it
    lastSelected = _navigationView.Menu.FindItem(e.MenuItem.ItemId);
    lastSelected.SetChecked(true);

    initFragmentByMenuId(e.MenuItem.ItemId);

    _drawer.CloseDrawers();
}
```

Also, you can just subscribe to the `DrawerClosed` event and do the same `lastSelected.SetChecked(false)`in there. `DrawerClosed` is only called once the drawer is fully closed.

Comment: But how exactly can I manage lastSelected in another Toggle-class? I have a class `CustActionBarDrawToggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle`     and a method there:                                                                                 ` public override void OnDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
 {
            base.OnDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }`